# UIView not detecting touch on landscape orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, landscape

I'm implementing a gallery with a UIView that contains UIScrollViews and UIButtons.

When the orientation is portrait, there's no problem, but when de orientation changes to landscape mode, the 300 pixels from bottom stops getting sensibility.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attach a tap gesture to a view the view needs to resize itself according to the superview new frame. You need to correctly set `autoResizingMask` property to your view the for this.

Comment: The problem is that, is not a resizing, I create the view when the iPad changes the orientation.
Even the iPad starts on landscape orientation, it doesn't works!

Comment: When the iPad starts it is ALWAYS in portrait home - check the properties of ur frame in ur viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 1):

i think you may set the static frame value. if so, set it as dynamic.
eg:

```
your_View=[UIVIew alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

or

```
your_view.frame = self.view.bounds;
```